# React unit testing, JEST + axios mock problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I have a problem with unit test with JEST and Axios. The mock does not work and I do not get data during the unit test. I have no idea why it happens. My only thought is that I mocked it in a wrong way since I use axios.client.get?

test:

```
jest.mock("axios");
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

describe("Test of products fetch", () => {
  test("render products", async () => {
    mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
      title: "product",
      description: "description",
      _id: "123",
      imageData: "",
      price: "15",
    });

    render(
      <ReduxProvider>
        <Products />
      </ReduxProvider>,
    );
    const productsList = await screen.findAllByRole("a");
    expect(productsList).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    expect(productsList).toBeLessThan(10);
  });
});
```

component

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async (): Promise<void> => {
      const prods = await getProducts(actualPage);
      setProducts(prods);
    };
    getProducts();
  }, [actualPage]);
<Fragment>
              {products.map((product) => (
                <ProductItem
                  key={product.title}
                  title={product.title}
                  imageData={decodeBase64(product.imageData)}
                  price={product.price}
                  id={product._id}
                />
              ))}
            </Fragment>
```

api-call

```
export async function getProducts(pageNum: number): Promise<IProduct[]> {
  const response = await productsClient.get<IProduct[]>(
    `/get-products?page=${pageNum}`,
  );
  const data = response.data;
  return data;
}
```

error: `const response = await productsClient.get<IProduct[]>( Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and implement the mock this way

```
mockAxios.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
  switch (url) {
    case '/product/123':
      return Promise.resolve({
      title: "product",
      description: "description",
      _id: "123",
      imageData: "",
      price: "15",
    });
    case '/product/124':
      return Promise.resolve({
      title: "product",
      description: "description",
      _id: "124",
      imageData: "",
      price: "145",
    });
    default:
      return Promise.reject(new Error(`product not found`));
  }
});
```